# keep an image at 120% of original size while resposive

Tags: html, css

How do you make image bigger than its original size and maintain responsive design in x and y direction?

I use this code to make it responsive. Works great, I would just like the image to be 120% of it's current height.

```
display: block; max-width: 100%;
```

Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L62mz8ug/).

Comment: width:100%; - Max width is different

Comment: responsiveness works with with max-width too. My question is how can I make height 120% and maintain responsiveness.

Comment: "height 120%"? What do you envision the width being?

Comment: if you want to maintain aspect ratio then you need to specify either height or width and let the other be auto. If you want to specify height then you will have to use overflow:hidden for the width if the width is larger than the height

Comment: How about adding the code you tried to your question. also include a fiddle so we can see exactly what you tried that didnt work

Comment: I added a fiddle with a dummy image. My localhost image is much much wider than it is tall. The goal is to have the image responsive, with the height of 130% or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you could do.

```css
.container{

  background: #ccc;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10%;
  position: relative;

}

.img-container{
  
  background: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  
}

.img-container img {
  width: 120%;
  margin-left: -10%;
  
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<html>
 
  <body>
  
    <div class="container">
      
      <p>Typewriter chia heirloom retro pickled 90's. Lo-fi neutra live-edge letterpress. Street art try-hard cold-pressed vinyl stumptown tacos. Post-ironic yr swag food truck, pour-over sartorial live-edge pork belly hell of truffaut blue bottle whatever beard. Intelligentsia succulents flannel art party, air plant try-hard roof party tilde. Kinfolk listicle iPhone biodiesel. Stumptown organic chambray umami ramps fashion axe intelligentsia, 90's leggings.</p>
      
      <div class="img-container">
        
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fhigh-resolution-photos.com%2Fstock_photos%2Froyalty_free_3.jpg&f=1">
        
        
      </div>
      
      <p>Typewriter chia heirloom retro pickled 90's. Lo-fi neutra live-edge letterpress. Street art try-hard cold-pressed vinyl stumptown tacos. Post-ironic yr swag food truck, pour-over sartorial live-edge pork belly hell of truffaut blue bottle whatever beard. Intelligentsia succulents flannel art party, air plant try-hard roof party tilde. Kinfolk listicle iPhone biodiesel. Stumptown organic chambray umami ramps fashion axe intelligentsia, 90's leggings. <a href="https://hipsum.co">Text from Hipster Ipsum</a></p>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
  
 </html>
```

**Modivation**

We want the image to be 20% bigger than the container. Thus we need to do two things.

1. Create an environment such that we can see the whole image. This is the rational of having the container. Notice that it is 80% of the width of the screen.
2. Create a reference 100% for the image to scale off of. In this case it would be the image container. Notice that it fills the entire container div.

Now that these two things are setup, we can create an image that makes its self 20% bigger than it would have normally been, whilst being responsive to the size of the screen (rather the div around it).

If you were to go one step further, you could add a media query that would limit the size of the image.

```
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .img-container img {
    max-width: 480px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is the image really at 120% of its height, while being at 100% of  its width?

Comment: @sanjihan It should be, if there is no constraint on both hight and width the other property is scaled with respect to the original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `transform` css function which can take one parameter for both width and heigh or two, first for width and second height. (1.2==120%)

```
transform: scale(1.2); /* Standard syntax */
-ms-transform: scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2); /* Safari */
```

this function scales the element from center. so i guess u would be happy using it.

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) is also a good document about scale and other css available transforms that you might want to read.